# Filtering node.js (express, mongoose) app

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to a node.js application (express, mongoose) and I want to give the option to the user to filter the data they receive through checkboxes. In the front end I store the user's choice in cookies (I do not know know if there is a better way) but I failed to filter the data in my database. The html code is that:

A modal that gives the user the option to check for specific data

```
<div id="modal">
    <div id="modalContent">
        <h3>Filters</h3><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' id="closeBtn" class='ionicon' viewBox='0 0 512 512'><title>Close</title><path fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='32' d='M368 368L144 144M368 144L144 368'/></svg>
    <div>
    <form method="GET">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="Vasilopoulos" value="Vasilopoulos">Vasilopoulos
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="Masoutis" value="Masoutis">Masoutis
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="Web Only" value="Web Only">Web Only
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" class="save-cb-state" name="In Store" value="In Store">In Store
        </div>

            <button type="submit">Αναζήτηση</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My model is that:
The checkboxes are filtering for storeName and/or offerType (The problem is when the user wants to filter both data)

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const offersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    imgLink: String,
    title: String,
    startPrice: Number,
    discountPrice: Number,
    pageLink: String,
    storeName: String,
    offerType: String,
    discountPercentage: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Offers", offersSchema);
```

The first two checkboxes are referring to StoreName attribute of my model and the last two are referring to offerType

The code in my controller is this:

```
async function getOffers(req) {
    const cookiesArray = Object.values(req.cookies);
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page || 1); 
    const sort = req.query.sort || "discountPrice";
    const itemsPerPage = 10;

    let products;
//If cookiesArray length is greater than 0 means that the user has check at least one checkbox
    if(cookiesArray.length !== 0) {
        
        products = await Offers.find({ offerType: { $in: cookiesArray}, storeName: { $in: cookiesArray } })
        .skip((page - 1) * itemsPerPage)
        .limit(itemsPerPage) 
        .sort(sort);
    } else {

        products = await Offers.find()
        .skip((page - 1) * itemsPerPage)
        .limit(itemsPerPage) 
        .sort(sort);
    }
    
    return {
        category: "offers",
        products,
        sort,
        currentPage: page,
        hasNextPage: itemsPerPage * page < totalProducts,
        hasPreviousPage: page > 1,
        nextPage: page + 1,
        previousPage: page - 1,
        lastPage: Math.ceil(totalProducts / itemsPerPage)
    }
}
```

getOffers is a helper function that my controller uses to fetch data. I tried to use the in operator but if the user check one or two values from the first two checkboxes and one or two values from the last two check boxes the in operator fails.

Comment: What does "cookiesArray" look like on the server?

Comment: cookiesArray contains the values from the checked checkboxes